# Array of greater elements

Tags: java, arrays

I'd like to create a method that recieves an array and a value to compare. It should return the numbers which are greater than the value compared in the form of an array.

For instance, `greaterThan([3, 4, 5, 6], 4])` should return `[5, 6]` and `greaterThan([3, 4, 5, 6], 5])` should return `[6]`.

Since the `length` of the `result` array is dynamic, I've incremented the size each time it finds a larger element.

```
static String greaterThan(int[] vectorCompare, int valueCompare)
{   
    Arrays.sort(vectorCompare);         // make it faster

    int size = 0;

    int[] result = new int[size];

    for (int value : vectorCompare)
    {
        if (valueCompare < value)
        {               
            size++;             
        }           
    }

    int[] resultCopy = Arrays.copyOf(result, size);

    // what to do next?

    return Arrays.toString(resultCopy);

}
```

Any tips for me? I thought of using `ArrayList` but I'm kinda stuck.

Comment: `int[] elements = Arrays.stream(vectorCompare).filter(i -> i > valueCompare).toArray()`

Comment: You have created a result array but you are not adding anything to it, why?

Comment: There is no need to create `result` (an empty array) and then copy it (resulting in a zero-filled array). Just create the array directly with `int[] result = new int[size];` after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to sort it, just collect the elements in a list and call toString on the contents. You can sort the list of collected values afterwards if the order is important.

```java
    static String greaterThan(int[] vector, int compare) {
        List<Integer> greater = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i : vector) {
            if (i > compare) {
                 greater.add(i);
            }
        }

        return greater.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting your input in the above method will actually make it slow. With normal array iteration and comparison your complexity will be O(n) while with sorting it would be O(nlogn). Instead you can try this.

```
static String greaterThan(int[] vectorCompare, int valueCompare)
   {
      List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int value : vectorCompare)
      {
         if (valueCompare < value)
         {
            list.add(value);
         }
      }
         return list.toString();
   }
```

By using Arraylist you would not be required to worry about the number of elements that are to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as below:

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(2);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(6);
    list.add(7);

    int valToCompare = 4;
    List<Integer> result = find(list, valToCompare);

    private static List<Integer> find(List<Integer> list, int val) {
        return list.stream().filter(v -> v > val).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: Also, `List<Integer> list = List.of(2,1,4,6,7);`

Comment: Yes, I agree. We can use it if we are using java 9 or above

Answer (score 0):

This is about as simple as it can get. This works with arrays.

```java
   public static int[] greaterThan(int[] numbs, int max) {
      return Arrays.stream(numbs).parallel().filter(a -> a > max).toArray();
   }
```

You can also do the same for a List.

```java
   public static List<Integer> greaterThan(List<Integer> numbs, int max) {
      return numbs.parallelstream().filter(a -> a > max).collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
```

In both cases, the List or array is turned into parallel streams of values. Those are filtered to allow only those that are greater than max thru the pipeline.  Then they are collected into a List or an array and returned.  This particular task is suited to parallel operations in multiple threads and will speed up execution, especially if your PC has multiple cores.

Even if you're new at Java, lambdas and streams are important features of the language and should be learned.

Comment: Lambdas and streams have their uses, but it is far more useful to get a solid foundation in knowing how to use basic control structures like loops, conditionals etc to put data into common data structures. And leave parallel streams right out of it: that's juggling chainsaws before you can walk.